# Getting Log10 axis in Graphics Function

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale, splines, plot-themes

In the output shown in the following image, I need x axis to be logarithmic (base 10) instead of linear. When I used ListLogLinearPlot function I got scattered points instead of the required B Spline curve. So how do I get x axis in log10 form at the same time getting a BSpline curve?[image]

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: pts1 = {{1, 1.480352}, {5, 0.927527}, {10, 0.83693}, {50, 
    0.760043}, {100, 0.7501427}};
Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts1]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {a,-k0}]